# How to bind the control on the form with variable

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am just start studying iOS developing watching Stanford iOS course, but it looks like I have already missing something.

I have a form with UILabel and UIButton.  When an user press the button the title of the button must be added to the text of label.

Here is my current CalculatorViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CalculatorViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *display;

@end
```

and here is a CalculatorViewController.m:

```
#import "CalculatorViewController.h"

@implementation CalculatorViewController

@synthesize display = _display;

- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSString *digit = [sender currentTitle];
    UILabel *myDisplay = self.display;
    myDisplay.text = [myDisplay.text stringByAppendingString:digit];
}

@end
```

The problem is that self.display (and myDisplay) variables have a nil value.  Looks like I need to do something to link my variable with control on the form.  What ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link the control, the `UILabel` in Interface Builder to the variable in your `CalculatorViewController` class.

It is very likely that the file's owner (talking about the Xib file) is your `CalculatorViewController`, so you need to Control+drag the file's owner (or the object representing your VC) to the control and you will be shown a menu with the possible `IBOutlet` variables declared in your class, so you select the one you want to represent the control.

You can check if this link is properly set in two ways: (1) Select the UILabel in Interface Builder and see if there's a connection to the variable in the Connections Inspector, or (2) In your code you'll see a bullet near the IBOutlet declaration, if the bullet is hollow the connections is not set, if the bullet is filled the connection is set.

Comment: Thanks.  I have done Control+Drag before, but look like this link is broken now.  I have recreate it and now all works fine.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of this line

```
UILabel *myDisplay = self.display;
```

You have already declared your label in your interface file

```
- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
   NSMutableString *string = [myDisplay.text stringByAppendingString:sender.titleLabel.text];
   myDisplay.text = string;
}
```